# sshfs error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, sshfs

[The other duplicate threads didn't help, so opening a news one]

I try to mount remote folder and get error like this:

```
sanjarbek@laptop:~$ sshfs -o sshfs_debug sshd@192.168.1.2:/remote/path /local/path/ 
SSHFS version 2.5
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I can login to the server like this:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss sshd@192.168.1.2
```

and it works.

The user is in the fuse group:

```
sanjarbek@laptop:~$ grep fuse /etc/group
fuse:x:1002:sanjarbek
```

Also:

```
sanjarbek@laptop:~$ ll /etc/fuse.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root fuse 280 Jun 20  2014 /etc/fuse.conf
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please add the debug information generated by the above command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316277/upgrade-openssh-key-exchange-kex-from-ssh-dss-to/316359#316359

Comment: @schaiba can you tell how to get it? I supplied `-o sshfs_debug` option, but it only provides the version of sshfs

Comment: @Jakuje Thank you. But it is not what I asked here. There, it seems to be about ssh, and adding dss as algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `~/.ssh/config` with the content

```
Host 192.168.1.2
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

It is the effective alternative to the thing you did on the command line (`ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss sshd@192.168.1.2`).

Or generate and set up a new key pair (DSA keys are no longer recommended).

Comment: Great! Thank you. The ssh now works without explicitly stating the ssh-dss.

Comment: No, actually this was the solution, apparently. After a restart the sshfs works now. Thanks @Jakuje.